# Handling multiple matches in regex in Hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I want to parse out negative decimal values in a expression in Hive and I have written the following regex,

```
select regexp_extract("abcsdfghj-117.3700631&poikse-118.244&",
'([-][1-9][0-9]*[.][0-9]+)&*') as output
```

While the regex seems to work well, it gives me only the first match of it. Is it possible to make hive give out all possible combinations ? Is there any function in hive to make that return all the matches?

I did google this and I was not able to find any answer. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `regexp_extract` takes 3 parameters. `(string, pattern, match_index)`

Comment: @cricket_007 I have already tried this one. I have 0 and 1 and I am getting -117.3700631 and for 2, it throws and error. I am just wondering if we can write a query to get output something like, -117.3700631, -118.244. Can you please help me in doing this?

Comment: I bet you have to write a UDF to get "all matches" as a list that you want. And here is the correct regex. https://regex101.com/r/KgTsAl/1

Comment: @cricket_007 - check answer :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. replace every `{prefix}{number}&` with `,{number}`
2. cut the result from the 2nd char (removing the first `,`)
3. split the result to array by `,`

---

```
hive> select split(substr(regexp_replace("abcsdfghj-117.3700631&poikse-118.244&",'.*?(-\\d+\\.\\d+)&',',$1'),2),',') as output;
OK
["-117.3700631","-118.244"]
```

Comment: Yeah, well, I like Java/Python UDF's more than regex :)