# Hive REGEXP_EXTRACT extract the second occurrence of a pattern

Tags: regex, hive

I am querying data in Hive and extracting a code from a column.  I recently discovered that due to data entry/business process issues, users have been overloading the field and entering two separate job codes when there should only be one.

Sample data from the column:

```
NOV2 WAA UW FOO DISPLAY_W2100008/ SOMETHING DISPLAY W2100106
```

I've been using `REGEXP_EXTRACT(column,'([A-Z]\\d{7})',1) as id` will correctly extract the first code `W2100008`, but I am unable to extract the second code `W21001061`.

I want to use REGEXP_EXTRACT twice and alias id_1 and id_2 so we can analyze the second codes referenced.  Is there a way to reference the second time the pattern is matched?

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(column,'_([A-Z]\\d{7})',0)` returns the first match

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(column,'([A-Z]\\d{7})',1)` returns the first match

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(column,'([A-Z]\\d{7})',2)` returns an error

The extracted value will be used to join to another column, so the result needs to return a single value, not an array.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Better solution is possible - extract all of them into array in Hive

Comment: Exact match: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125647/handling-multiple-matches-in-regex-in-hive

Comment: Another better idea is to use `REGEXP_EXTRACT(column,'[A-Z]\\d{7}.*?([A-Z]\\d{7})',1) as id2`

Comment: @leftjoin - I reviewed the link you referenced before I posted this question and I still do not see how it would solve my problem.  I've updated the question to explain that the value returned will be used in a join and hence cannot be an array.

Comment: @wiktorStribizew Thank you for your `id2` example. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @wiktorStribizew I don't understand how this is a duplicate of matching strings in Java when I can't use Java for this task and the code referenced wouldn't run in Hive.  Can you please explain why you think that this question is answered there?

Comment: Please read the marked topic and if it didn't answer your question, edit accordingly.

Comment: @LeighF. Yes, if t does not help, let know.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all `'.*?([A-Z]\\d{7})'` with `delimiter(space) + ([A-Z]\\d{7})`. Remove first space using `trim`, split by `' '` to get array:

```
hive> select split(trim(regexp_replace('NOV2 WAA UW FOO DISPLAY_W2100008/SOMETHING DISPLAY W2100106','.*?([A-Z]\\d{7})',' $1')),' ');
OK
["W2100008","W2100106"]
```

Get first element:

```
hive> select split(trim(regexp_replace('NOV2 WAA UW FOO DISPLAY_W2100008/ SOMETHING DISPLAY W2100106','.*?([A-Z]\\d{7})',' $1')),' ')[0];
OK
W2100008
Time taken: 0.065 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

And second element is

```
split(trim(regexp_replace('NOV2 WAA UW FOO DISPLAY_W2100008/ SOMETHING DISPLAY W2100106','.*?([A-Z]\\d{7})',' $1')),' ')[1]
```

better use subquery to parse array one time.

```
select display_array[0] as id_1 , display_array[1] as id_2
from
(
select split(trim(regexp_replace('NOV2 WAA UW FOO DISPLAY_W2100008/ SOMETHING DISPLAY W2100106','.*?([A-Z]\\d{7})',' $1')),' ') as display_array
)s;
```

Use `explode()` if you want each element per row.

Comment: OP only needs to get the second occurrence of the pattern, not all occurrences. Replacing, splitting, trimming and retrieving via index is too much overhead, isn't it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew "I want to use REGEXP_EXTRACT twice and alias id_1 and id_2 "

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree with you. If only two elements, there is no need to get array

Comment: Well, I understood that literally, that OP needs a separate REGEXP_EXTRACT call to get the value separately. And I [got confirmation from OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271742/hive-regexp-extractextract-the-second-occurrence-of-a-pattern/51293140?noredirect=1#comment89563426_51271742) that my suggestion works as expected.