# Get max value next to same input in a string

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

I am working on Hive:

I have the following string:

```
D.07.01.01=1;B=NUL;A=NUL;D.07.01.01=NUL;R=1;D.07.01.01=2;D.07.01.08=2;D.07.01.07=1;D.07.01.06=2;D.07.01.05=1;D.07.01.04=2;D.07.01.03=1;F=YES;D.07.01.02=1
```

For a given code (`D.07.01.01`) I would like to get the max integer next to all its occurences, here in the above String I have `D.07.01.01=1`, `D.07.01.01=NUL` and `D.07.01.01=2`.

Desired result is 2.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I managed to write the following in order to have a list with all values for my desirec code (1, 2 and Nul) so I can apply `greatest` function on later:

```
select split(regexp_replace('D.07.01.01=1;B=NUL;A=NUL;D.07.01.01=NUL;R=1;D.07.01.01=2;D.07.01.08=2;D.07.01.07=1;D.07.01.06=2;D.07.01.05=1;D.07.01.04=2;D.07.01.03=1;F=YES;D.07.01.02=1', '.*D\\.07\\.01\\.01=(\\d+).*', '$1'), ';')
```

But this only returns ["2"].

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything that runs hive to test for sure. But this runs on a hive-ish platform. This is very brittle, you'll definitely want to make sure it's handling unclean values properly if you can have them (ex. D.07.01.01= with leading or trailing spaces). Hopefully it's food for thought if nothing else.

Rationale

It looks like your values are semicolon delimited, so if you explode each element to rows you are not limited by hive's lackluster regex support (handling arrays of matches seems to be a hurdle). Don't take that as gospel, hive may have support for this or canonical ways to handle it that just are not obviously documented.

Then cast(replace(els, 'D.07.01.01=', '') as integer) will try to cast every character that's not 'D.07.01.01=' as an integer. This will be null for anything that isn't D.07.01.01=.

Then the max() gets the largest integer, with nulls of course ignored.

```
SELECT
  max(cast(replace(els, 'D.07.01.01=', '') as integer))
FROM
  (
    select
      'D.07.01.01=1;B=NUL;A=NUL;D.07.01.01=NUL;R=1;D.07.01.01=2;D.07.01.08=2;D.07.01.07=1;D.07.01.06=2;D.07.01.05=1;D.07.01.04=2;D.07.01.03=1;F=YES;' as search_string
  ) raw_value lateral view explode(split(search_string, ';')) elements_delim_by_sc AS els
WHERE els like 'D.07.01.01=%' -- here in case you can have an element with just an integer.
```

Comment: This works when I test it alone in Hive, but when I integrate it in my 200 lines query it returns : Unsupported SubQuery Expression Currently SubQuery expressions are only allowed as Where and Having Clause predicates
Any posibility to have something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125647/handling-multiple-matches-in-regex-in-hive/42128682#42128682
I am pretty noob in regex.. .

Comment: @Haha Hard to say without seeing the query, sometimes putting stuff in a CTE helps isolate delicate syntax. Just tested this with multi-record sample data and it still holds good. I did see that answer, it wouldn't run on my platform. But it was well received so it's probably solid.